# Notepad++: Add leading zero(s) to lines but up to 9 digits

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, text-editing

I have these numbers

```
94349850
999445183
999445183
94173345
54303954
42588251
150425435
74140053
1234547
12345678
123456789
```

I need them to be exactly **9 digits** and if any is not then to add a leading zero
So the result that I am looking for is this

```
094349850
999445183
999445183
094173345
054303954
042588251
150425435
074140053
001234547
012345678
123456789
```

Could you pls suggest what search\replace regular expression to use?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You can do that in two step process, 1) add 9 `0`'s in front of each line. 2) Keep only the last 9 digits from each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from [Leading Zeros](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16230/leading-zeros) on Notepad++ community forum:

- Find what: `^(\d{9})|(\d{8})|(\d{7})|(\d{6})|(\d{5})|(\d{4})|(\d{3})|(\d{2})|(\d)$`
- Replace with: `(?{1}\1)(?{2}0\2)(?{3}00\3)(?{4}000\4)(?{5}0000\5)(?{6}00000\6)(?{7}000000\7)(?{8}0000000\8)(?{9}00000000\9)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to get the job done properly.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved. Visit [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two steps:

First, prefix all lines with zeroes so all lines contain at least 9 digits:

```
Search: ^
Replace: 000000000
[x] Regular expression
[ ] . matches newline
```

`^` means: The beginning of a line

Second, use this regex to cut off excess zeroes from the beginning of all lines:

```
Search: ^0*(\d{9})$
Replace: \1
```

The search regex means: Find lines that start with any number of zeroes `0*`, followed by exactly 9 digits `\d{9}` before the end of the line `$`. The 9 digits are marked as a group `( )` which can be referenced in the replace box as `\1`. The entire match (i.e. the whole line) will be replaced with the contents of this group.